# bash script: how to diff two files after stripping prefix from each line?

Tags: linux, bash, timestamp, diff

I have two log files. Each line is formatted as follows:

```
<timestamp><rest of line>
```

with this timestamp format:

```
2015-10-06 04:35:55.909 REST OF LINE
```

I need to diff the two files modulo the timestamps, i.e. I need to compare lines of the two files without their timestamps. What linux tools should I use?

I am on a RedHat 6 machine running bash if it makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first generate the two files to compare with the header removed using the cut command like this :

```
cut -f 3- -d " " file_to_compare > cut_file
```

And then use the diff command.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create temp files: use bash [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

```
diff <(cut -d" " -f3- log1) <(cut -d" " -f3- log2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'cut'

```
cat file1 | cut -b23- > file1cut
cat file2 | cut -b23- > file2cut

diff file1 file2
```

Comment: I used cat, then piped it to a cut, which accepts it as a stream.

Comment: It's just an unecessary process and pipe.

Answer (score 0):

To print all fields but the first two the `awk` utility (and programming language) can be used:

```
awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}' file1 > newfile1

awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}' file2 > newfile2

diff newfile1 newfile2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as your're looking for a tool why not just use a Kompare. Its very powerful and well known which is used by most developers who uses Linux.

https://www.kde.org/applications/development/kompare/
https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdesdk/kompare/using.html

Kompare is a GUI front-end program that enables differences between source files to be viewed and merged. It can be used to compare differences on files or the contents of folders, and it supports a variety of diff formats and provide many options to customize the information level displayed.